# Strategy for deserializing a class that has changed in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have this class

```
[Serializable]
public class myClass() : ISerializable
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, 
                              StreamingContext context)
        {
        // Some code
        }

    public myClass(SerializationInfo info, 
                   StreamingContext context)
        {
        // Some code
        }
}
```

I have hundreds of these object in my database. I am now ready to publish a new version of my app where the class has morphed to

```
[Serializable]
public class myClass() : ISerializable
{
    public int a;
    public string b;
    public int c;
    public bool d;

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, 
                              StreamingContext context)
        {
        // Some code
        }

    public myClass(SerializationInfo info, 
                   StreamingContext context)
        {
        // Some code
        }
}
```

How would one deserialize an object serialized based on the first version with the de-serialization constructor of the second.

Are there also strategies for future version proofing my second version of the class?

Comment: Make a converter program that reads objects of the first type, produces objects of the second type, and replaces the old ones with new. Running that program should take long, if you are talking about hundreds, not millions of records.

Comment: There's a dedicated MSDN article about it.  Better start there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms229752%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without preparation on your part, you may need to resort to a hack: when your `public myClass` deserialization constructor gets the value of `bool d`, enclose the code in `try`/`catch`, and set `d` to its default value when you catch an exception.

In the future, add an `int` value `"__ver"` (or any other name that does not collide with arguments that you pass to `info.AddValue`), and set it to a constant that you maintain in your class to indicate compatible and incompatible changes in serialization:

```
public class myClass : ISerializable {
    private const int __ver = 4;
    public int a;
    public string b;
    public int c;
    public bool d;

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, 
                          StreamingContext context) {
        info.AddValue("__ver", ver);
        info.AddValue("a", a);
        // and so on
    }

    public myClass(SerializationInfo info, 
               StreamingContext context) {
        switch(info.GetInt32("__ver")) {
            case 3: 
                // Deserialize prior version
            break;
            case 4: 
                // Deserialize current version
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only issue is that all the current instances in the database dont have the __ver field on them, so you wont be able to retrofit this implementation.

Comment: `SerializationInfo` doesn't have something like `ContainsKey()`? I think that would be very useful here.

Comment: I think you could use `MemberCount` or `GetEnumerator()` to avoid the `try`/`catch`.

Comment: @PeteDavis Correct - this is the subject of the first paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Serializable classes are great for passing them around through the same version of software, but you hit this issue quickly when using it for persistence. If you are going to store objects as [BLOBs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object), then maybe use something like [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) which allows serialization versioning by allowing for optional fields.

Given your current predicament all you can do to get it to work imediatly is put a try catch around the new fields, and then default them if they are not there:

```
protected myClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    c = info.GetInt32("Value_C"); 
    try
    {
        b = info.GetBoolean("Value_B");
    }
    catch (SerializationException)
    {
        b = true;
    }
}
```